# How can i know if there is a disconnection on the client side, in unity socketIO implementation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a multiplayer game in unity and it's socketIO implementation, i want to know if there is a method to know if the client has been disconnected due to network connection or any other thing,  so he can be notified either to reconnect or exit.

Comment: What network API are you using?

Comment: Worth reading: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Comment: @PerformanceFreak what do you mean by network api ?

Comment: You're creating a multiplayer game? What API are you using? There is Unity's unet, photon, raw tcp, udp. No one knows until you tell or show us

Comment: I am using SocketIO (HTTP) since it is a turn based mulitplayer game